# "0.8em" to ".8em" , is both same?

Tags: css

"0.8em" to ".8em" , is both same? which should we use?

Comment: Is this not something you can just try out and see what happens?  (I'm not a web developer so I'm not sure if the "try it and see" technique works or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in css file is to be interpreted by the browser, modern browser render the same page with 0.8em or .8em.

If you want to have less trafic (css files smaller) use .8em otherwise if you want full comprehension of your styles by other users use 0.8em.

In my case i use .8em, cause anyone can interpret that as 0.8em.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same, but 0.8 tends to be easier to read than .8.

Comment: That's fine. Readability is not a priority for a css compressor.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid Usually people commit their uncompressed code (for further development) and deploy the compressed code.

Answer (score 0):

0.8em seems clearer, and it can remove the annoyance of not seeing the . sometimes. Both are the same though.

Answer (score 0):

use 0.8. Remember clarity is code results in long term benefits!